# Android Как работать с фоном  в EditText?

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, activity

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в андроид приложениях работать с задним фоном? Можете скинуть статью как делают такие вещи как строчки и задний фон как тут

[image]

Такое в блокнотах делают.

Comment: ссылка нерабочая... 404

Comment: Лично мне кажется, что это кастомный EditText с подчёркиванием строк и с выставленным в `android:background` цветом.

Comment: @xTIGRx, иллюзию подчеркивания делают путем высчитывания высоты шрифта( dp ), и последующей отрисовкой линий на объекте Canvas.

Comment: @woesss, я уже сделал...Да и как поставить вам Плюс я ХЗ на этом сайте....И еще, а как узнать координаты откуда начинается текст, чтобы рисовать линии...по сторонам я понял что надо указать размер экрана. А вот чтобы рисовать под словами чтобы на всех экранах нормлаьно отображалось...я хз как

Comment: @xTIGRx, кнопки нет потому что кол-во комментариев ограничено

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует как минимум 3 различных способа создания собственных UI компонентов в Android.

```
 1. Наследование от стандартного( в вашем случае - TextView ) и переопределение метода onDraw()

 2. Создание составных элементов путем наследования от одного из классов базовой разметки( LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, AbsoluteLayout и т.д ) и загрузка XML представления внутрь посредством LayoutInflater

 3. Создание абсолютно новых View со специфичным поведением, наследуясь от класса View и переопределяя всю логику работы и взаимодействия с экземпляром уникального виджета.
```

Для вашего случая вполне подойдет первый способ.

Comment: А нелезья выставить как кибудь в XML коде это?..ведь за отрисовку XML отвечает, а учитывая то что подчеркивание в блокноте меняться не будет то его просто нужно при создании EditText указать..допустим даже как нибудь типо <u></u>????

Comment: Через xml получится только статичное подчёркивание. Например, вы написал очень много текста, и он не помещается в пределы экрана, пoэтому EditText включает прокрутку. А прокрутить можно так, чтобы текст был на линии подчёркивания, а не над ней. Некрасиво.

Comment: Сейчас по гуглю как в канве рисовать и отпишусь если что не получиться)

Comment: Строка не появляется
http://pastebin.com/Dbq2miD0

Comment: @xTIGRx, Вы написали класс EditText, но его ли Вы поместили в xml-раметку? Чтобы не было путаницы не называйте кастомные классы именами стандартных.

Comment: XML main_notepad

http://pastebin.com/9ZR07jcr
@woesss, почему не работает?

Comment: @xTIGRx, 0xFFh скорее всего ошибся - вместо TextView надо использовать EditText.  
И вообще, попробуйте код из этого [ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6111460).

Comment: Потому что Вы туда поместили стандартный `EditText`, а не Ваш. Переименуйте его, объявите как public и вынесите в отдельный класс-файл. После этого он должен появиться в разделе "Custom & Library View" визуального редактора xml, где Вы и сможете его добавить в разметку. Ещё предостережение: при этом у класса будет вызываться конструктор с 2-мя параметрами `(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` - поэтому инициализацию Paint нужно перенести.

Comment: > @woesss, код в студию плиз...я то я нихрена не понял, потому что раншье ничего подобного не делал

А Вы хотите чтобы я это сделал за Вас??? Тогда Вам нужно ещё погрызть гранит науки, а не браться за работу.